# libvirt-python 4.0.0 missing method

Tags: python, libvirt

I need to listen for storage pool events using `libvirt-python` but the [`storagePoolEventRegisterAny`](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt-python/blob/master/libvirt-override-virConnect.py#L353) method is not present when installing with `pip` (`pip install 'libvirt-python==4.0.0'`) or even when building/installing from the repo

I'm not an experienced python developer(~1 month) so maybe there's something that i miss about the way that libvirt-python is installed/configured ?!

On Ubuntu 16.04

```
connection = libvirt.openReadOnly("qemu+tcp://<ip>/system")
connection.storagePoolEventRegisterAny(...)
```

plus the appropriate event loop

Comment: can you post your code